# What's the best way to exchange data between devices locally?

Tags: ios, swift, macos-sierra

I want to send data from 4-7 iPads to a MacBook and back for an application I plan on making that uses all devices and I want to avoid using a server for exchanging data. Also I would like to avoid connecting the devices over a local wifi network, as I would like my application to work regardless of wifi availability. 
Is there a way of doing this using Bluetooth or a wired solution? Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best way is using apple Multipeer Connectivity, you can connect up to 7 nearby devices via Bluetooth, Wifi, or creat a local Wifi: https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity